# Lists: Idiomatic way of filtering similar elements

Tags: list, kotlin

I am searching for the opposite of [`distinct`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct.html).

In a list with `[ "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d" ]` I only want to keep `"a"` and `"b"` because they appear multiple times.

A solution for this could be the following:

```
val similarsList = mutableListOf<String>()
list.filter { 
    if (similars.contains(it))
        return@filter true
    similars.add(it)
    false
}.distinct()
```

This will remove every element that matches an already contained element before it. In the `list` object all elements appearing multiple times will be stored after `filter`. `distinct` in this case cleans elements that appeared three or more times.

I am **searching for an idiomatic way** of doing exactly that, the opposite of `distinct`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A small improvement to the solution provided by [@gil.fernandes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2735286/gil-fernandes) can be made by using the API introduced in the Kotlin 1.1 standard library: [`.groupingBy { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/grouping-by.html). Instead of creating the groups right away, it creates a lazy [`Grouping`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-grouping/index.html), which can then be queried. In particular, we can ask it for [`.eachCount()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/each-count.html), which returns `Map<T, Int>`:

```
val l = listOf("a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d")

val result = l.groupingBy { it }.eachCount().filterValues { it > 1 }.keys
```

It is a little bit more efficient than using `.groupBy { ... }`, because it does not store the groups in the lists.

Comment: How would we do this on a Map?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, you can get `keys`, `values`, or `entries` (pair of a key and its value) from a Map, then group them the same way.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to filter out duplicates (non distinct items) you could try:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val l = listOf( "a", "a", "b", "c", "b", "d" )
    println(l.groupBy { it }.filter { it.value.size > 1 }.keys)
}
```

This prints out:

```
[a, b]
```

Explanation: `l.groupBy { it }` produces a grouped map with this content:

```
{a=[a, a], b=[b, b], c=[c], d=[d]}
```

Then a filter is applied to this map, filtering by the values (which are lists) with a length superior to 1: `filter { it.value.size > 1 }`.

Finally the keys are extracted with `keys`.

Comment: I think the grouping approach is very nice and I did not know about this functionality!

Comment: @creativecreatorormaybenot This is a possible approach. I wonder, if there are other elegant ones; I am waiting for more answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question has been answered already but in case anyone is looking for a more efficient method than using groups.

Where you can do it this way

```
val list = listOf(0,1,2,3,4,5,0)

//Gives you group of duplicated numbers. In this case just 0
val group = list.groupBy{it}.filter{it.values.size>1}.keys
```

While this fully works but if you need efficiency it is better to just use for loops and HashSets

From my testing I found this to be more efficient and faster

```
val list = listOf(0,1,2,3,4,5,0)
val mutableList = mutableListOf()
val set = HashSet<String>()

for(l in list) {
  if(set.contains(l)) mutableList.add(l)
  set.add(l)
}
```